# How to stop the setInterval()?

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval, clearinterval

below is the script of `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()`..

I have searched for `clearInterval()` to stop the `setInterval()`... I implemented that code, but it is not working..

What i am trying to achieve here is that, for example, there are 8 predator and 3 prey.. The setInterval will start when there is more Predators than Prey, so the Prey will reduce 3 while the Predator will increase 3 more.. And when the number of prey hit 0.. The predator should stop increasing since there is no more prey left..

The problem here is that, when the prey hit 0, the predator is still increasing.. I added in `clearInterval()` but it is not working.. May i know what went wrong?

```
<script>
    function startAni() {
        if ((document.getElementById('amount').value) >= (document.getElementById('amount5').value)) {
            alert("Predator is more than prey! FRENZY TIME!");
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                Remove3(), removevalue3(), Add(), addvalues();
                if (document.getElementById('amount5').value = "0") {
                    alert("No more Prey!");
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }, 5000);
        } else {
            alert("Prey is more than Predator! Revenge time!")
        }
    }
</script>
```

Many thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: Can you please incude your HTML ? or even better create a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: In particular, are you sure that there's an input field called "amount5" on the page?

Comment: Check your JavaScript errors in case you don't know for sure ;-)

Comment: Hey, ManseUK, sorry for late reply, my HTML is like this, 

<INPUT type="button" value="+" onClick="Add();"> 
<input type="text" id="amount" value=0  maxlength="3" size="1">
<INPUT type="button" value="-" onClick="Remove();">


<INPUT type="button" value="+" onClick="Add3();"> 
<input type="text" id="amount5" value=0  maxlength="3" size="1">
<INPUT type="button" value="-" onClick="Remove3();">

Comment: by the way, here is the link to jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/KAK3T/11/
Not sure, why the function is not working, but the html code is there as you requested.. Thanks again for helping!

Comment: @Amazinglykai its kind of working now - the loop is being executed - but there are still variables not defined (such as `x` and `y`) ... http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/KAK3T/12/ I suggest you use your browser debugger (or firefox) and look at the errors 1 by 1

Comment: Yeah, hmm.. Nv mind, anw, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 7):

You need to ensure that there is an actual `input` on the DOM with the id `amount5` because if there is then `document.getElementById('amount5').value = "0"` will be `true` and will clear your interval immediately ...

But

```
if (document.getElementById('amount5').value = "0") {
```

should be

```
if (document.getElementById('amount5').value == "0") {
```

in javascript you use double equals (`==`) to compare.

Comment: The odd thing is, shouldn't the mistake result in the interval timer being canceled immediately? That is, if there really is an "amount5" input field.

Comment: @Pointy yes that probably would - unless `document.getElementById('amount5').value` is null or undefined ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm thinking.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
if(document.getElementById('amount5').value = "0"){
```

You should use `==` instead of `=`, otherwise your condition is always truthy. Having said that, that statement would immediately kill the timer.

Comment: The string "0" is true, because it's not the empty string.

Comment: @Pointy hmm that's true, but that would immediately kill the timer =/

Comment: Yes I agree. Perhaps the problem is that there's no "amount5" element on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of looking at it is using `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` and `clearInterval`:

```
function doAdd() {
    Remove3(), removevalue3(), Add(), addvalues();
    if (document.getElementById('amount5').value = "0") {
        alert("No more Prey!");
        // thats it, no more recursion as your stop condition has been met
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(doAdd, 5000); // continue as there is more to be done
    }
}
setTimeout(doAdd, 0); // start it off
```

Comment: This would stop the timer, but it wouldn't alert anything :)

Comment: Was just a demonstration of the idea. Of course more code to complete the full logic as in the questions needs to be in there. :)

Answer (score 0):

You made mistake on setting the interval variable scope. You should define it as global variable.

If you define it in "startAni" function, the variable cannot be accessed by nested function in "startAni" function.

You should define as:

```
<script>
    var interval;//define it here
    function startAni() {
        if ((document.getElementById('amount').value) >= (document.getElementById('amount5').value)) {
            alert("Predator is more than prey! FRENZY TIME!");
            interval = setInterval(function () {  //do not redefined interval as var just use it here
    ....

</script>
```